# Backbone.js - printing out the collection and collection.models give different results

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a fetch in my Backbone collection as follows.

```
var Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  get_items:function(data) {
    this.fetch({
      data:data,
      success:function() {
        console.log(items);
      }
    });
  });
}

var items = new Items();
items.get_items({id:1});
items.get_items({id:2});
```

In each of the console.log statement, I expect the contents of the collection to be different because I gave different parameters. But in Chrome, no matter what "id" value I give, the content of the collection doesn't change.

However, if I do

```
var Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  get_items:function(data) {
    this.fetch({
      data:data,
      success:function() {
        console.log(items.models);
      }
    });
  });
}

var items = new Items();
items.get_items({id:1});
items.get_items({id:2});
```

where I specifically printout "items.models", I can see that the list of models in the collection has indeed been changed.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing two different scenarios here: the collection is not just an array of models.. it has a lot of stuff attached to it. The collection's 'models' property is where all the data is. Only that is the absolute source of truth - anything else is either lying or doing something it's not supposed to.

Edit: 
To add to this, why not reference 'this' instead of 'items'? i.e. this.models? After all, if you're wondering what is inside of the collection that you are working with, having to reference a global variable is a bit silly :) (and rather bad practice).

Edit #2:
Also, the 'fetch' is asynchronous unless specified otherwise.. so if you're trying to get a consistent, reproducible result, doing two fetches in a row isn't going to give it to you. If one of the requests is even a millisecond slower than the other for whatever reason then your results will be out of order anyway.